# F1 OPT Visa Tax return queries

Tags: united-states, income-tax, f1-student-visa

I have few questions on tax returns filing, please help.

1. I am on F1 EAD OPT visa, can I still file returns on 1098-E form.
2. Many were suggesting to do paper file rather than e-file. Can I e-file too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> can I still file returns on 1098-E form.

1098-E is not a tax return form, it is the form used to report student loan interest.

What you're probably asking is whether the student loan interest is deductible for you. They are, [looking at the IRS instructions](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970/ch04.html#en_US_2015_publink1000178272).

> Can I e-file too.

Form 1040-NR can be e-filed.

Comment: It looks like I can show my interest payments while I was on EAD OPT visa too. Pls correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I though that's what you were asking about...